# wordpress term exists condition not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running this inside a loop in WordPress:

```
<?php

    if ( term_exists('term'=> 'pdf'))
    { 
       echo 'PDF' ;
    }
    else if ( term_exists('term'=> 'ppt'))
    { 
       echo 'PPT' ;
    }
    else ( term_exists('term'=> 'mov'))
    {
        echo 'MOV' ;
    }

?>
```

I've created a taxonomy called `file-formats` and these terms above ( `pdf`, `mov`, `ppt` ) are in my `file-formats` taxonomy.

And I'm trying to `echo` specific stuff, depending in which term the post is in.

But the PHP script above just seems to brake the site. Can anyone help?

---

**UPDATE**

This still not working...

```
<?php

    if (term_exists( 'term' => 'pdf' )) {

        echo 'PDF' ;

    }
    else if (term_exists( 'term' => 'ppt' )) {

        echo 'PPT' ;

    }
    else if (term_exists( 'term' => 'mov' )) {

        echo 'MOV' ;

    }
    else {

        echo '' ;

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `else` part. Should be:

```
if ( term_exists('term', 'pdf')) { 
     echo 'PDF' ; 
 }
 else if ( term_exists( 'term', 'ppt')) { 
   echo 'PPT' ; 
 }
 else { 
    echo 'MOV' ; 
 }
```

Reference: [term_exists($term, $taxonomy)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response...
`
<?php

 if (term_exists( 'term' => 'pdf' )) {
 
  echo 'PDF' ;
  
 } else if (term_exists( 'term' => 'ppt' )) {
 
  echo 'PPT' ;
  
 } else if (term_exists( 'term' => 'mov' )) {
 
  echo 'MOV' ;
  
 } else {
 
  echo '' ;
 
 }
 
?>
`

But still not working? Get white screen

Answer (score 0):

First argument for `term_exists` should be your term ('pdf' or 'ppt' etc), second parameter - taxonomy ( 'file-formats' in your case ).

```
if (term_exists( 'pdf', 'file-formats' )) {
   echo 'PDF' ;
} else if (term_exists( 'ppt', 'file-formats' )) {
   echo 'PPT' ;
} else if (term_exists( 'mov', 'file-formats' )) {
   echo 'MOV' ;
} else {
   echo '';
}
```